# My div disappears after I position it as absolute

Tags: html, css, css-position

I know what absolute positioning in CSS is & how it is used, so I thought of playing with it. I created 3 `div`s mainly and set the position of the `.red` one as absolute and to my surprise, the `.blue` one goes missing. Why is that? Shouldn't the `.red` one be out of the flow and its position should have been altered rather than the `.blue` ones?

```css
.red{
  background-color: red;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
}
.blue{
  background-color: blue;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
.green{
  background-color: green;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="red">
    </div>
    <div class="blue">
    </div>
    <div class="green">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have ````.parent```` any css?

Comment: I know what absolute positioning in CSS `?`

Comment: refer z-index which makes div visible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because of `out of flow`. As you can see in the snippet below, in the first `.parent` element, `.red` is visible, whereas `.blue` is not. The `.blue` element is present and is hidden behind `.red`. In the second `.parent`, the `.red` element has one more class `.change` changing the `z-index` property to `-1`. This makes the `.red` hide behind `.blue.`.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

.change {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="red">
  </div>
  <div class="blue">
  </div>
  <div class="green">
  </div>
</div>

<br/><br/>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="red change">
  </div>
  <div class="blue">
  </div>
  <div class="green">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is by default is the z-index of red div 1 and hence it's always showing above the blue one?

Comment: The default z-index value of all the elements is `0`. The positioned elements are `out of flow` elements. Which is why even after having same `z-index` value, `.blue` was being overlapped by `.red`.

Comment: Your comment seems to be the actual answer, and I think is right. Being out-of-flow is what matters here, not the z-index.

Answer (score 1):

Your `.red` div is above your `.blue`. For testing, add `opacity: 0` to the red one and you will notice that it is still there.

This is because the `.red` has `position: absolute` while the blue and green one have `position: relative`. So they do not affect each other in their positons.

A `relative` element is positioned *relative* in its parent.
A `absolute` element is positioned *absolute* in its parent, where the top left corner is the origin. *relative* and *absolute* elements do not affect each other in their positions.